# I can not set Set Text in Card View name and surname

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have problem with set text in card view. I have 3 activist. First activity is list , second activity which show edit text which I complete data Person next acttivty 3 summary click buton go to MainActivty. When click to MainActitvty display error.

```
04-05 09:21:06.879 1035-1035/magdalena.pl.callmistake E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: magdalena.pl.callmistake, PID: 1035
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String magdalena.pl.callmistake.Person.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at magdalena.pl.callmistake.PersonAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PersonAdapter.java:41)
                                                                            at magdalena.pl.callmistake.PersonAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PersonAdapter.java:18)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
```

my PersonAdapter

```
    public class PersonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

        public List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

        Person person;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public PersonAdapter(LayoutInflater layoutInflater) {
            this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
        }

        @Override
        public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.
                    from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);

            return new PersonViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int position) {
            person = personList.get(position);

            holder.name.setText(person.getName());
            holder.surname.setText(person.getSurname());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return personList.size();
        }

        public void addPerson(Person person) {

            int position = getItemCount();
            personList.add(position, person);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        public class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


            public TextView name, surname;


            public PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
                surname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_surname);
            }



        }
    }

class Person 

public class Person implements Parcelable
{

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String description;

    protected Person(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        surname = in.readString();
        email = in.readString();
        phone = in.readString();
        description = in.readString();
    }


    public Person(String name, String surname, String email, String phone, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return null;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
        return null;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public static Creator<Person> getCREATOR() {
        return CREATOR;
    }

    public static final Creator<Person> CREATOR = new Creator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public Person createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Person(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Person[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Person[size];
        }
    };

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(surname);
        parcel.writeString(email);
        parcel.writeString(phone);
        parcel.writeString(description);
    }
}
```

What is wrong ?

all code
https://github.com/Madzia123/CallInert

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: Please specify the line on which you're getting the error and I'll suggest you to post only relevant code.

Comment: Check your `personList` - error here specifies that `person` model at the position is null. Make sure you are properly filling `personList`.

Comment: @Ewelina See my answer below. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, In the onBindViewHolder method the person object is null. And you are trying to invoke getName() method on null reference. So it is causing the error. Make sure to have valid reference to Person object.

Comment: when add in holder.name.setText("Magda"); and  holder.surname.setText("Gut"); add card on list

Answer (score 0):

You are adding null person to personList at

```
public void addPerson(Person person) {
    int position = getItemCount();
    personList.add(position, person);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

That's why when you call

```
person = personList.get(position);
```

it returns `null`

try this

```
public void addPerson(Person person) {
    if(person==null){
      Log.e("error","person is null");
      return;
    }
    int position = getItemCount();
    personList.add(position, person);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Person person = personList.get(position);
holder.name.setText(person.getName());
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43226624/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

From your attached `logs`, seems that you are getting `NullPointerException` when calling `Person.getName()` from your adapter's `onBindViewHolder()`.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String magdalena.pl.callmistake.Person.getName()' on a null
>   object reference

**Solution:**

**Update your `PersonAdapter` as below:**

```
public class PersonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    // Person List
    public List<Person> personList;

    public PersonAdapter(Context context, List<Person> persons) {
        this.context = context;
        this.personList = persons;

        layoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);

        // View holder
        PersonViewHolder holder = new PersonViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Person
        Person person = personList.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(person.getName());
        holder.surname.setText(person.getSurname());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return personList.size();
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person) {

        int position = getItemCount();
        personList.add(position, person);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView name, surname;

        public PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            surname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_surname);
        }
    }
}
```

**In your `Activity` do this:**

```
..........
.................
Context mContext;

// RecyclerView
RecyclerView recyclerView;
PersonAdapter personAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

// Values
List<Person> listPerson;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .......
    ............

    // Context
    mContext = this;

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    // Set your recyclerView  layout manager

    // Person List
    listPerson = new ArrayList<Person>();

    // Add some person data to list from API call or from Database
    // Here I added some for test purpose
    listPerson.add(new Person("Hello Android", "Android", "google@gmail.com", "21132342423", "Lorem ipsum"));
    listPerson.add(new Person("Hello Android", "Android", "google@gmail.com", "21132342423", "Lorem ipsum"));


    // specify an adapter
    personAdapter = new PersonAdapter(mContext, listPerson);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(personAdapter);
}

...............
...........................
```

Hope this will help you~

Answer (score -2):

first pass the data from where you call this adapter.

```
adapter = new PersonAdapter(getContext(),(ArrayList<Person>) list);
```

use arraylist.method to access class method.

```
 holder.name.setText(person.personList(position).getName());
```